# Numerical calculations using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, calculations

Assume I have defined a constant `\valueA` as

```
\def\valueA{25 2 sqrt sqrt mul }
```

I would like to devide this value by the square root of 2, so I tried

```
\pstFPdiv\valueB{\valueA}{2 sqrt}
```

but this is not valid notation. What is the correct way to define the constant `\valueB` as `\valueA`/sqrt(2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The defined constants can be used in both TeX world and PS world.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% #1: (optional) the number of digits after decimal point, the default is 6 
% #2: (mandatory) the name of variable to create
% #3: (mandatory) mathematics expression in infix form
\newcommand\const[3][6]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const{valueA}{3*root(root(2,2),2)}
\const{valueB}{valueA/root(2,2)}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,10)
    \rput(!valueA valueB){(\valueA,\valueB)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: My answer here had actually been invented, reviewed, and improved by you and egreg several decades ago (in my own questions). Accepting this answer implies accepting yours and egreg's as well. :-)

Comment: @PGFTricks I thought I recognised that code:-)

Answer (score 4):

```
\valueA  2 sqrt div
```

would work once passed to the PS interpreter, so if I understand correctly you just want

```
\edef\valueB{\valueA  2 sqrt div }
```

Comment: Okay. This (with `\def` instead of `\edef`) was actually what I did at first; I just assumed that `\pstFPdiv` was somehow 'better' to use inside a `pspicture` environment. Thank you, David.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I knew pstricks well (and last looked at the manual) around 1990, I can still make it do stuff, but don't rely on me to know the _best_ way these days:-)

Comment: Well, I know you are a TeXpert; your suggestions are normally the best way to do TeX stuff. `:)`